# Azure IoT Hub - Data Visualization Tutorial - No Data Shown

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-iot-hub

Have successfull completed the "[Connect Raspberry Pi to Azure IoT Hub (Python)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-python-get-started)" and "[Use iothub-explorer to send and receive messages between your device and IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-explorer-cloud-device-messaging)" tutorials, setting up a Raspberry Pi that is sending simulated data to the cloud.

Using iot-explorer I can see that all is working great, messages are being sent from the Pi to the cloud and the iot-explorer monitor is pulling and showing them, perfect!

But, now I have tried the "[Visualize real-time sensor data from your Azure IoT hub by using the Web Apps feature of Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps)" tutorial, and all went perfectly fine except when I load the web page no data is being shown on the graph at all.

Pi is running and sending the messages through, which I can see within the Azure portal and in the iot-explorer monitor, but nothing showing on the graphs.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi chivs688, can you see the data showing now?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the messages in iot-explorer monitor indicate messages are sending successfully to build-in endpoint messages/events of Azure IoT Hub.

And if you can't see any data in the graph, it is a blank graph like this:

[image]

It means the web app deploy and running successfully but no data arrived in the web app.

Then what you need to check is the web app settings:

1. Make use you set the right **IoT Hub connection string**. It has the following format: `HostName=[YOUR HUB NAME].azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=[KEY]`. You can find it in IoT Hub -> Settings -> Shared Access Polices -> iothubowner -> Connection string-primary key.
2. Set the **consumer group** created in [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps#add-a-consumer-group-to-your-iot-hub) of the tutorial.
3. Enable **WebSocket**.

Settings in Web App will like this:

[image]

[image]

Setting(consumer group) in Azure IoT Hub:

[image]

If it is still not working feel free let me know.